# How to create enterprise in Android Management API without customer interaction for getting enterprise token?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, android-management-api

This is controller code. Here I have provide how I'm creating enterprise. But currently I'm unable to create enterprise without enterprise token. Which I'm getting from customer, when customer registering thyself on play.google.com.

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
    using Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3;
    using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
    using Google.Apis.AndroidManagement.v1;
    using Google.Apis.Services;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Google.Apis.AndroidManagement.v1.Data;
    using System.Security.Claims;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using QRCoder;
    using System.Drawing;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
    using IHostingEnvironment = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment;

    namespace xProducts_RETL.Web.Controllers
    {
        public class EmmController : Controller
        {
            private readonly ILoggerManager _loggerManager;
            private readonly IEmmMapper _iEmmMapper;
            private readonly IConfiguration _iConfiguration;
            private SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
            private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
            private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;
            private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

            //private static readonly string ProjectId = "xpdemo";
            private static readonly string ProjectId = "xdemo";
            private static readonly string PolicyId = Zoo_ManagedPolicy";
            private static readonly string PolicyId2 = "Zoo_WorkPolicy";
            private static readonly string PolicyId3 = "Zoo_ManagedPolicyx";
            //private static readonly string COSU_APP_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc";
            //private static readonly string TestEnterpriseName = "enterprises/xxxxj";
            private static readonly string TestEnterpriseName = "enterprises/xxxx8";
            private const string Package_Outlook = "com.microsoft.office.outlook";
            
            public EmmController(ILoggerManager loggermanager, IEmmMapper iEmmMapper, IConfiguration iConfiguration, SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,IHostingEnvironment environment)
            {
                _loggerManager = loggermanager;
                _iEmmMapper = iEmmMapper;
                _iConfiguration = iConfiguration;

                _signInManager = signInManager;
                _userManager = userManager;
                _roleManager = roleManager;
                _environment = environment;
            }

            [HttpGet]
            public IActionResult CreateEnterprise(EnterpriseDto enterpriseDto, string x)
            {
                try
                {
                    //bind dropdowns
                    enterpriseDto.EnterpriseList = _iEmmMapper.GetEnterpriseList();
                    enterpriseDto.CreatedEnterpriseList = _iEmmMapper.GetGooglePlaySignedupEnterpriseList();

                    //fetch superadmin info
                    var superadminData = _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("SuperAdmin").Result;
                    var superadminId = superadminData[0].Id;
                    var enterpriseList = _iEmmMapper.GetEnterprises().Where(x => x.OwnerIdentityId == superadminId && x.EnrollmentToken != null && x.EnrollmentTokenWP != null).ToList();
                    foreach (var enterprise in enterpriseList)
                    {
                        enterpriseDto.EnterpriseId = enterprise.EnterpriseId;
                    }
                    //
                    return View(enterpriseDto);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _loggerManager.LogError($"Something went wrong inside CreateEnterprise get action: {ex.Message}");
                    return View(enterpriseDto);
                }
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public IActionResult CreateEnterprise(EnterpriseDto enterpriseObj)
            {
                //populate default dropdown values
                EnterpriseDto enterpriseModel = new();
                enterpriseModel.EnterpriseList = _iEmmMapper.GetEnterpriseList();
                enterpriseModel.CreatedEnterpriseList = _iEmmMapper.GetEnterpriseList();

                if (enterpriseObj.Id != 0 || enterpriseObj.Id2 != 0)
                {
                    #region serviceAccountAuthenctiactionFlow
                    //read service a/c creds
                    ServiceAccountCredential? credential;
                    string fileName = "service_account_key.json";
                    string path = Path.Combine(this._environment.WebRootPath, "ZeroTouchCredJSON", fileName);
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                    {
                        credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream)
                                             .CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidmanagement")
                                             .UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
                    }

                    // Create a zero-touch enrollment API service endpoint.
                    var service = new AndroidManagementService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
                    {
                        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                        ApplicationName = ResourceMsg.EMMAppName
                    });
                    #endregion

                    //create signup url
                    var signupData = service.SignupUrls.Create();
                    signupData.ProjectId = ProjectId;
                    signupData.CallbackUrl = _iConfiguration.GetValue<string>("AppSetting:CallBackURL");
                    var response = signupData.Execute();

                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        //create enterprise
                        var enterpriseData = service.Enterprises.Create(new Enterprise());
                        enterpriseData.ProjectId = ProjectId;
                        enterpriseData.SignupUrlName = response.Name;
                        enterpriseData.EnterpriseToken = "EAJmqckyhc_cep8KkQ-NDU3SG4uC7WfJk1oumRM9SqDPZ-jzMY6D-K-bbWaYHMDvMNsc-faLjwLdyF50yTZIKv_JK_vxEXxp2rPVKkDxzce8whACXz261yaM";
                        var enterpriseResponse = enterpriseData.Execute();
                    }
                }
                return View(enterpriseModel);
            }

            //[GoogleScopedAuthorize(AndroidManagementService.ScopeConstants.Androidmanagement)]
            //[HttpPost]
            //public async Task<IActionResult> CreateEnterprise([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth, EnterpriseDto enterpriseObj)
            //{
            //    EnterpriseDto enterpriseModel = new();
            //    try
            //    {
            //        //bind dropdowns
            //        enterpriseModel.EnterpriseList = _iEmmMapper.GetEnterpriseList();
            //        enterpriseModel.CreatedEnterpriseList = _iEmmMapper.GetEnterpriseList();

            //        if (enterpriseObj.Id != 0 || enterpriseObj.Id2 != 0)
            //        {
            //            #region OAuthFlow
            //            // Check if the required scopes have been granted. 
            //            if (await auth.RequireScopesAsync(AndroidManagementService.ScopeConstants.Androidmanagement) is IActionResult authResult)
            //            {
            //                return authResult;
            //            }

            //            //The required scopes have now been granted.
            //            GoogleCredential cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
            //            var service = new AndroidManagementService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            //            {
            //                HttpClientInitializer = cred.CreateScoped(AndroidManagementService.Scope.Androidmanagement),
            //                ApplicationName = ResourceMsg.EMMAppName
            //            });


            //            //Fetch client information from GCP
            //            dynamic name = "";
            //            dynamic email = "";
            //            if (User.Identity is ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity)
            //            {
            //                var listk = claimsIdentity.Claims.Select(x => new { x.Type, x.Value }).ToList();
            //                name = listk[3].Value;
            //                email = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            //            }

            //            //noob | superadmin
            //            if (email != "xy@gmail.com")
            //            {
            //                TempData["VerificationFailed"] = "You have logged in with a customer account. Please login with owner account to continue.";
            //                return View();
            //            }


            //            //var enterpriseRes = _iEmmMapper.GetEnterprises().Where(x=> x.ClientEmail == email);
            //            //if(enterpriseRes!= null)
            //            //{
            //            //    TempData["MsgSignupFailed"] = "There is already an Enterprise exist. Please try with a different mail to add a new Enterprise.";
            //            //    return View(enterpriseModel);
            //            //}
            //            #endregion

            //            //check userId existance
            //            string ownerUserId = "";
            //            var users = _userManager.Users.ToList();
            //            foreach (var user in users)
            //            {
            //                if (user.Email == "xx@yopmail.com")
            //                {
            //                    ownerUserId = user.Id;
            //                    break;
            //                }
            //            }

            //            //Enterprise Signup
            //            if (enterpriseObj.Id != 0 && enterpriseObj.ActionFlag == "Signup")
            //            {
            //                //create signup url
            //                var signupData = service.SignupUrls.Create();
            //                signupData.AccessToken = cred.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync().Result;
            //                signupData.ProjectId = ProjectId;
            //                signupData.CallbackUrl = _iConfiguration.GetValue<string>("AppSetting:CallBackURL");
            //                //signupData.Service.
            //                var response = signupData.Execute();
            //                var ownerGoogleAccountId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

            //                if (ownerGoogleAccountId != null && ownerUserId != null)
            //                {
            //                    //assign client info to model
            //                    enterpriseObj.ClientName = name;
            //                    enterpriseObj.ClientEmail = email;

            //                    //assign signup data to vmodel
            //                    enterpriseObj.SignupUrlName = response.Name;
            //                    enterpriseObj.SignupUrlURL = response.Url;
            //                    enterpriseObj.OwnerIdentityId = ownerUserId;
            //                    enterpriseObj.OwnerGoogleAccountId = ownerGoogleAccountId;

            //                    //insert data into database
            //                    var result = _iEmmMapper.CreateUpdateEnterprise(enterpriseObj);
            //                    if (result == 1)
            //                    {
            //                        TempData["MsgSignupUrl"] = "Signup URL for the enterprise generated successfully.";
            //                        return View(enterpriseModel);
            //                    }
            //                }
            //                TempData["VerificationFailed"] = "Please login with current account details.";
            //                return View(enterpriseModel);
            //            }

            //            //Create Enterprise
            //            if (enterpriseObj.Id2 != 0 && enterpriseObj.ActionFlag == "Enterprise")
            //            {
            //                var response = _iEmmMapper.GetEnterprises().Where(x => x.Id == enterpriseObj.Id2).FirstOrDefault();
            //                if (response != null)
            //                {
            //                    var enterpriseData = service.Enterprises.Create(new Enterprise());
            //                    enterpriseData.AccessToken = cred.UnderlyingCredential.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync().Result;
            //                    enterpriseData.ProjectId = ProjectId;
            //                    enterpriseData.SignupUrlName = response.SignupUrlName;
            //                    enterpriseData.EnterpriseToken = response.EnterpriseToken;

            //                    //enterprise generated
            //                    var enterpriseResponse = enterpriseData.Execute();
            //                    enterpriseModel.EnterpriseNameAPIFormat = enterpriseResponse.Name;
            //                    var EnterpriseNameResponse = enterpriseResponse.Name;
            //                    //enterpriseModel.EnterpriseToken = enterpriseData.EnterpriseToken;

            //                    //fetch enterprise from db
            //                    //var resultEnterprise = _iEmmMapper.GetEnterprises();
            //                    //if (resultEnterprise != null)
            //                    //{
            //                    //    foreach (var enterprise in resultEnterprise)
            //                    //    {
            //                    //if (enterprise.ClientEmail == email)
            //                    //{
            //                    //prepare commonpolicies obj
            //                    CommonPoliciesDto commonPolicies = new();

            //                    //initialize model to assign apps into it
            //                    commonPolicies.ApplicationDtoList = new List<ApplicationsDto>();
            //                    var appModel = new ApplicationsDto();

            //                    //enterprise Id >noob
            //                    string[] enterpriseFullId = enterpriseResponse.Name.Split('/');
            //                    string enterpriseId = enterpriseFullId[1];

            //                    //create two different new policies
            //                    string[] enterpriseArr = response.EnterpriseNameRequested.Split(' ');
            //                    string enterpriseFirstName = enterpriseArr[0];
            //                    string ManagedProfilePolicyName = enterpriseFirstName + "_FMDefaultPolicy";
            //                    string WorkProfilePolicyName = enterpriseFirstName + "_WPDefaultPolicy";

            //                    //var IsPolicyIdExist = _iEmmMapper.GetDevices().Where(x => x.PolicyId == PolicyId3 && x.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId).Any();//noob
            //                    //if (IsPolicyIdExist)
            //                    //{
            //                    //    SetDefaultPoliciesForExistingPolicy(TestEnterpriseName, PolicyId3);
            //                    //}
            //                    //else
            //                    //{
            //                    //    //if policyId not assigned previously with any token
            //                    //    GenereateEnrollmentTokenForNewPolicy(TestEnterpriseName, PolicyId3);
            //                    //}

            //                    var IsManagedPolicyIdExist = _iEmmMapper.GetCommonPolicies().Where(x => x.PolicyId == ManagedProfilePolicyName && x.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId).Any();//noob
            //                    if (!IsManagedPolicyIdExist)
            //                    {
            //                        //if policyId not assigned previously with any token
            //                        GenereateEnrollmentTokenForNewPolicy(EnterpriseNameResponse, ManagedProfilePolicyName, ResourceMsg.FullyManged);
            //                    }

            //                    var IsWorkPolicyIdExist = _iEmmMapper.GetCommonPolicies().Where(x => x.PolicyId == WorkProfilePolicyName && x.EnterpriseId == enterpriseId).Any();//noob
            //                    if (!IsWorkPolicyIdExist)
            //                    {
            //                        //if policyId not assigned previously with any token
            //                        GenereateEnrollmentTokenForNewPolicy(EnterpriseNameResponse, WorkProfilePolicyName, ResourceMsg.Work);
            //                    }


            //                    #region localFunctionToGenerateTokenThruEnterpriseIdAndPolicyId
            //                    void GenereateEnrollmentTokenForNewPolicy(string enterpriseNameAPIFormat, string myPolicyId, string policyProfileType)
            //                    {
            //                        //forming policy name
            //                        string policyName = enterpriseNameAPIFormat + ResourceMsg.POLICIES_FORMAT + myPolicyId;

            //                        //set a default hardware policy to newly registered device
            //                        var appliedPolicyData = service.Enterprises.Policies.Patch(DefaultHardwarePolicies(myPolicyId), policyName).Execute();
            //                        if (appliedPolicyData != null)//noob
            //                        {
            //                            enterpriseModel.PolicyName = policyName;

            //                            //Create Default Policy in Database
            //                            CommonPoliciesDto commonPoliciesModel = new()
            //                            {
            //                                UserIdentityId = ownerUserId,
            //                                EnterpriseId = enterpriseId,
            //                                PolicyId = myPolicyId,
            //                                PolicyName = policyName,
            //                                PolicyType = "Default",
            //                                PolicyProfileType = policyProfileType,
            //                                PolicyNameApiFormat = policyName,
            //                                //
            //                                MaximumTimeToLock = 0,
            //                                StatusBarDisabled = false,
            //                                KeyguardDisabled = false,
            //                                WifiConfigDisabled = false,
            //                                MobileNetworksConfigDisabled = false,
            //                                BluetoothDisabled = true,
            //                                BluetoothContactSharingDisabled = true,
            //                                UsbFileTransferDisabled = true,
            //                                AdjustVolumeDisabled = true,
            //                                ScreenCaptureDisabled = true,
            //                                ShareLocationDisabled = true,
            //                                AutoDateAndTimeZone = ResourceMsg.AUTO_DATEANDTIMEZONE_UNSPECIFIED,
            //                                CameraDisabled = true
            //                            };
            //                            var result = _iEmmMapper.CreateUpdateCommonPolicies(commonPoliciesModel);
            //                            if (result == 0)
            //                            {
            //                                //TempData["MsgCmnPolicies"] = ResourceMsg.PoliciesCreatedSuccessfully;
            //                            }
            //                            var rtrvPolicy6 = _iEmmMapper.GetCommonPolicies().ToList();
            //                            var rtrvPolicy = _iEmmMapper.GetCommonPolicies().Where(x => x.PolicyId == myPolicyId).FirstOrDefault();
            //                            if (rtrvPolicy != null)
            //                            {
            //                                if (rtrvPolicy.PolicyProfileType == ResourceMsg.FullyManged)
            //                                {
            //                                    //create enrollmentToken for Fully Managed Device with a policy name & assign created user
            //                                    //removed to setup KIOSK mode -> .SetUser(user.AccountIdentifier)
            //                                    EnrollmentToken token = new DemoEnrollmentToken().SetPolicyName(myPolicyId).SetDuration(ResourceMsg.ThirtyDaysInSecond).SetAllowPersonalUsage(ResourceMsg.PERSONAL_USAGE_DISALLOWED);
            //                                    var tokenResponse = service.Enterprises.EnrollmentTokens.Create(token, enterpriseNameAPIFormat).Execute();
            //                                    var eToken = tokenResponse.Value;
            //                                    enterpriseModel.EnrollmentToken = eToken;
            //                                }
            //                                else
            //                                {
            //                                    if (rtrvPolicy.PolicyProfileType == ResourceMsg.Work)
            //                                    {
            //                                        //User setup [can't be use in KIOSK mode setup or only work for work profile]
            //                                        var user = new User
            //                                        {
            //                                            AccountIdentifier = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            //                                        };

            //                                        //create enrollmentToken for work profile Device with a policy name & assign created user
            //                                        EnrollmentToken token2 = new DemoEnrollmentToken().SetPolicyName(myPolicyId).SetUser(user.AccountIdentifier).SetDuration(ResourceMsg.ThirtyDaysInSecond).SetAllowPersonalUsage(ResourceMsg.PERSONAL_USAGE_ALLOWED);
            //                                        var tokenResponse2 = service.Enterprises.EnrollmentTokens.Create(token2, enterpriseNameAPIFormat).Execute();
            //                                        var eToken2 = tokenResponse2.Value;
            //                                        enterpriseModel.EnrollmentTokenWP = eToken2;
            //                                    }
            //                                }


            //                            }
            //                            else
            //                            {
            //                                _loggerManager.LogError($"There is an error occured in GenereateEnrollmentTokenForNewPolicy local function. {ResourceMsg.InvalidPolicy}");
            //                                TempData["Failure"] = ResourceMsg.InvalidPolicy;
            //                            }
            //                        }
            //                    }
            //                    #endregion
            //                    enterpriseModel.Id = enterpriseObj.Id2;
            //                    enterpriseModel.EnterpriseId = enterpriseId;
            //                    if (enterpriseModel.Id != 0 && enterpriseModel.EnterpriseId != null)
            //                    {
            //                        //update data into database
            //                        var entResponse = _iEmmMapper.CreateUpdateEnterprise(enterpriseModel);
            //                        if (entResponse == 1)
            //                        {
            //                            TempData["MsgEnterprise"] = ResourceMsg.EnterpriseCreatedSuccessfully;
            //                        }
            //                    }

            //                    //}
            //                    //    }
            //                    //}
            //                }
            //                else
            //                {
            //                    TempData["Failure"] = ResourceMsg.ContactTechnicalTeam;
            //                }
            //            }
            //        }
            //        return View(enterpriseModel);
            //    }
            //    catch (Google.GoogleApiException gex)
            //    {
            //        string msgErr = "Error in " + this.GetType().ToString();
            //        _loggerManager.LogError($"{msgErr}{gex.Message}");
            //        TempData["Failure"] = ResourceMsg.ContactTechnicalTeam;
            //        return View(enterpriseModel);
            //    }
            //    catch (Exception ex)
            //    {
            //        string msgErr = "Error in " + this.GetType().ToString();
            //        _loggerManager.LogError($"{msgErr}{ex.Message}");
            //        TempData["Failure"] = ResourceMsg.ContactTechnicalTeam;
            //        return View(enterpriseModel);
            //    }
            //}
```

I'm facing this issue from a long time. Please share your feedback and help on this. Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to create an enterprise:

- **Customer-managed enterprise:** This is the recommended way to create an enterprise. This is the one you are using in your code and it requires an enterprise token.
- **EMM-managed enterprise:** This is not the preferred method to create an enterprise, but it is still possible to create and manage an EMM-managed enterprise using this method. EMM managed enterprises can be created programmatically without customer intervention.

This guide covers how to create [EMM-managed enterprises](https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-enterprise#emm-managed_enterprises). With this method, **EMMs** have full control over an enterprise’s lifecycle.

> **Note:** In the future, it would not be possible to create any EMM-managed enterprises using the enterprises.create method.

I suggest reviewing the process of creating a [Customer-managed Enterprise](https://developers.google.com/android/management/create-enterprise#customer-managed_enterprises) by having the Enterprise IT admin complete the sign-up flow, as this is the preferred method.